# NPM Audit Error -- Regular expression denial of service

Tags: angular-cli, npm-audit, chokidar

<-----CLOSED  SOLVED ---->

I am learning how to use Angulur.

I am getting 5 moderate errors that I could not solve inside of a project folder.  I had spent 2 all days on it without a success.

I hope one of you could tell me how to remedy this.  I had searched the Internet but it appears it points that this may be bug that I have to wait.  However, I think I have all latest versions according to 2nd picture.
I appreciate if you could advise me.  Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally got this working.

What I did as follows:

1. npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
2. Delete User/xxxx/AppData/npm-cache folder manually.  I don't know why the command npm clean cache --force did not work due to warn message (npm WARN using --force Recommended protected disabled.
3. commit all changes
4. ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
5. npm audit -- to make sure there is no more error